# CefSharp configurations in USD 4.1

Tags: cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I'm trying to automate the USD 4.1 (MS Dynamics CRM 365) which is using a CefSharp to render HTML content.
While exploring the internet I found this GitHub CefSharp I am looking for some help.

Is this github project is for UI Automation purposes?
How to enable the force-renderer-accessibility in cefsharp, I do have the CefSharp.xml inside the USD 4.1 installation?

Comment: CefSharp.xml is likely the IntelliSense file that ships with CefSharp, open it and have a look. CefSharp doesn't use any xml config files so it would only be if they implemented something in the application. If they used the WinForms version then UI automation is possible though it will depend if they have disabled command line argument processing.  By default CEF will process command line,  just launch the exe with --force-renderer-accessibility if they used the WPF version and command line args are enabled you can use puppeteer Sharp to control the browser. I've never used dynamics com 365

Answer (score 0):

As per the following documentation, USD application enables force-renderer-accessibility by default or if you have set the option value to be true explicitly

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/unified-service-desk/chrome-process?view=dynamics-usd-4.2#accessibility-support-with-chrome-process